# What is the correct way to use Android Room with Kotlin Coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

While learning how to use Kotlin Coroutines recently, have been read several relevant articles. But one of them confuse me: [Coroutines On Android (part III): Real work](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-on-android-part-iii-real-work-2ba8a2ec2f45)

As it pointed out:

> Note: Room uses its own dispatcher to run queries on a background
>   thread. Your code should not use withContext(Dispatchers.IO) to call
>   suspending room queries. It will complicate the code and make your
>   queries run slower.

It seems to make sense at the time I saw these paragraph, but when I open an Android project and trying to dive into, the problem shows up, Android Studio warns me:

> suspend function 'yourMethod' should be called only from a coroutine
>   or another suspend function

I'm now freezing here, because the article told me not to use `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`. And I am now wondering should I use `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` or use `GlobalScope.launch` to run my queries?

Comment: "And I am now wondering should I use withContext(Dispatchers.Main) or use GlobalScope.launch to run my queries?" -- use `launch()` (or perhaps `async()` and `await()`) with a suitable `CoroutineScope`. That could be `GlobalScope`, but usually there are better options (`viewModelScope` on a `ViewModel`, `lifecycleScope` on an activity, `viewLifecycleScope` on a fragment, a custom `CoroutineScope` as seen [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-patterns-for-work-that-shouldnt-be-cancelled-e26c40f142ad), etc.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks, I am looking for a solution for work that shouldn’t be canceled, and the link you provide is exactly what I'm looking for, I'll check this out. Thank you for your help!

Comment: refer https://github.com/sasisachin12/SQLRoomSample

Comment: try withContext(NonCancellable) {} if you don't want your suspend fun operations cancelled

Comment: @sasikumar your solution seems no help to this question. The "suspend" keyword in your project is marked as "redundant" by  Android Studio.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cfcyYO7osnk&list=PLQkwcJG4YTCT0RouHZ6sQlE4JE6VyD2zO&ab_channel=PhilippLackner 
You can watch this series of 6 videos

Answer (score 1):

So let's say you have a Room DB DAO as below,

```kotlin
@Dao
interface RoomDao
{
    @Query("SELECT * FROM $TABLE_NAME WHERE $ITEM_ID = :itemId")
    suspend fun getEntry(itemId : String) : Entry?
}
```

Remember that `getEntry` is a `suspend fun` and can only be called inside a `suspend fun` or inside a `coroutineScope` or using a `runBlocking` method(these are how the coroutine framework handles/manages all its work)

So now, there are a few ways to call the above method

**1. Use the `coroutineScope` provided by the fragment, activity or viewModel**

Using `coroutineScope` means that you have launched `coroutine`(think of it same as Java `Thread` but lightweight) and are not willing to wait for it. There are two ways to the same `launch` and `async`. In terms of way of execution they both does the same thing. They only return different types of handlers to you to modify the launched `coroutine`. One returns `Job` by which you can query the `coroutine` status and cancel it, the other returns the `Deffered` object by which you can access the returned value of the launched `coroutine`
This is applicable when you want to access the values returned by the Room DB directly.
The below code demonstrates how to do the same

1. In a fragment

```kotlin
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // your onViewCreated related code
    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch { 
        val entry = DbInstance.getDao().getEntry("<yourEntryId>")
    }
}
```

2. In a activity

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // your onCreate related code
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        val entry = DbInstance.getDao().getEntry("<yourEntryId>")
    }
}
```

3. In a viewModel

```kotlin
fun launchEntryCall(itemId: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val entry = DbInstance.getDao().getEntry("<yourEntryId>")
    }
}
```

4. Use `GlobalScope`**(Not recommended)**

```kotlin
fun launchEntryCall(itemId: String) {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        val entry = DbInstance.getDao().getEntry("<yourEntryId>")
    }
}
```

`GlobalScope` is not recommended as you yourself have to manage the lifecycle of the coroutine launched as `GlobalScope` is not integrated with `coroutineScopes` provided by the android classes they tend to complicate the code.

Here `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope` in fragment and `lifecycleScope` in activity is provided by the android library(You may need to [add](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#dependencies) those)

**2. Call in other `suspend fun`**

This will be helpful to you in cases you want to call multiple similar functions and operate on those to return something meaningful. Let's say you make a function which calls the previous `getEntry` and checks if the following item is deleted or not from the server and returns the item and null if the item is deleted. You can model the same with below code

```kotlin
suspend fun getItemIfNotDeleted(itemId: String): Entry? {
    val entry = DbInstance.getDao().getEntry(itemId)
    entry ?: return null
    return if (isDeleted(entry.url)) {
        null
    } else {
        entry
    }
   
}
```

**3. Use `runBlocking`(**Not recommended in production code**)**

`runBlocking` blocks the execution of the current thread till the coroutine returns or throws an exception. So let's say you want to test the above function a test you can call `runBlocking` and get the result and assert on it like below code snippet

```kotlin
@Test
fun verifyItemReturnedIsNotNull() {
    val entry = runBlocking {
        DbInstance.getDao().getEntry("<yourEntryId>")
    }
    assertNotNull(entry)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use Dispatchers.IO on your repository, in your viewModel you can use viewModelScope.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31873103)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can call a suspend function without calling from another suspend function or calling from inside a coroutine.

I think the author wanted to mention that we should avoid using the IO Dispatchers and rather rely on the default ones when launching coroutines.